# Gather Columns based on separator

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(RANGER.MAE = c(0.22, 0.22, 0.21, 0.23, 0.20),
            RANGER.RMSE = c(0.33, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.28),
            QUANTILE.MAE = c(0.22, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.18),
            QUANTILE.RMSE = c(0.35, 0.50, 0.49, 0.49, 0.29))

print(df)

  RANGER.MAE RANGER.RMSE QUANTILE.MAE QUANTILE.RMSE
       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1       0.22        0.33         0.22         0.35 
2       0.22        0.48         0.21         0.5  
3       0.21        0.48         0.21         0.49 
4       0.23        0.48         0.22         0.49 
5       0.2         0.28         0.18         0.29
```

and I want to make the prefix, such as "RANGER" and "QUANTILE" a column and the suffix such as "MAE" and "RMSE" a column.

My desired output is:

```
            MAE    RMSE
RANGER      0.22   0.33
RANGER      0.22   0.48
RANGER      0.21   0.48
RANGER      0.23   0.48
RANGER      0.20   0.48
QUANTILE    0.22   0.35
QUANTILE    0.21   0.50
QUANTILE    0.21   0.49
QUANTILE    0.22   0.49
QUANTILE    0.18   0.29
```

I tried `gather(df)` but I think I need one more argument to separate the columns by the suffix as well. I would like to do this in tidyverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 separate(var, into = c("var", "col")) %>%
 spread(col, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  var        MAE  RMSE
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 QUANTILE  0.22 0.35 
 2 RANGER    0.22 0.33 
 3 QUANTILE  0.21 0.5  
 4 RANGER    0.22 0.48 
 5 QUANTILE  0.21 0.49 
 6 RANGER    0.21 0.48 
 7 QUANTILE  0.22 0.49 
 8 RANGER    0.23 0.48 
 9 QUANTILE  0.18 0.290
10 RANGER    0.2  0.28
```

Answer (score 1):

Het is a data.table approach, thus should run *fast* on wharever size data.frame you like to throw at it..

I know you requested tidyverse, but data.table is really (ok.. in my opinion) *the* tool that is best equipped to handle this kind of operation. The benchmarks prove my point (I think).

```
library(data.table)
library(forcats)

#we are almost there with a one-liner data.table melt
ans <- melt( setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns( MAE = "MAE", RMSE = "RMSE") )

#    variable  MAE RMSE
# 1:        1 0.22 0.33
# 2:        1 0.22 0.48
# 3:        1 0.21 0.48
# 4:        1 0.23 0.48
# 5:        1 0.20 0.28
# 6:        2 0.22 0.35
# 7:        2 0.21 0.50
# 8:        2 0.21 0.49
# 9:        2 0.22 0.49
# 10:       2 0.18 0.29

#just set the factors of the variable to the desired character string
ans[, variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, c("RANGER", "QUANTILE"))][]

#    variable  MAE RMSE
# 1:   RANGER 0.22 0.33
# 2:   RANGER 0.22 0.48
# 3:   RANGER 0.21 0.48
# 4:   RANGER 0.23 0.48
# 5:   RANGER 0.20 0.28
# 6: QUANTILE 0.22 0.35
# 7: QUANTILE 0.21 0.50
# 8: QUANTILE 0.21 0.49
# 9: QUANTILE 0.22 0.49
# 10:QUANTILE 0.18 0.29
```

## update: benchmarks

some benchmarks on a 100000-row df

```
n = 100000
set.seed = 123
df <- tibble(RANGER.MAE = runif( n, 0, 1),
             RANGER.RMSE = runif( n, 0, 1),
             QUANTILE.MAE = runif( n, 0, 1),
             QUANTILE.RMSE = runif( n, 0, 1))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  data.table = {
    dt <- copy( df )
    ans <- melt( setDT(dt), measure.vars = patterns( MAE = "MAE", RMSE = "RMSE") )
    ans[, variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, c("RANGER", "QUANTILE"))][]
  },
  tidyverse = {
    dt <- copy( df )
    df %>%
      rowid_to_column() %>%
      gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
      separate(var, into = c("var", "col")) %>%
      spread(col, val) %>%
      select(-rowid)
  }, times = 5
)


# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq        max neval
# data.table   2.050403   3.970056   3.82328   4.112553   4.423759   4.559629     5
# tidyverse  478.239258 563.140243 577.40732 572.687597 598.821034 674.148455     5
```

Comment: I love the approach but speed isn’t an issue here